# Radial Menu With Pyside/PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

Basically I am trying to create a radial menu like this

[image]

I was using QPainter and here is a attempt from my side. But I can't figure out how to add a click event on the pixmaps. Is there any lib available for this ?

[Images Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlwvgee3tl3l8hp/images.zip?dl=0)

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import os
RESPATH = "/{your_folder}/radialMenu/res"

class RadialMenu(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    addButton     = 1
    disableButton = 2
    clearButton   = 3
    exportButton  = 4
    infoButton    = 5
    runButton     = 6
    scriptsButton = 7
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RadialMenu, self).__init__(parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(71, 71, 71, 0)))
        tempPen =  QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(178, 141, 58), 20.0, QtCore.Qt.CustomDashLine)
        tempPen.setDashPattern([4, 4, 4, 4])
        painter.setPen(tempPen)
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 150, 150)
        topX = 0
        topY = 0
        pixmap1 =  QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(RESPATH, "add.png"))
        painter.drawPixmap(topX + 50, topY - 8, pixmap1)
        pixmap2 = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(RESPATH, "disable.png"))
        painter.drawPixmap(topX + 90, topY - 5, pixmap2)
        pixmap3 = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(RESPATH, "clear.png"))
        painter.drawPixmap(topX - 10, topY + 70, pixmap3)
        pixmap4 = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(RESPATH, "export.png"))
        pixmap4 = pixmap4.transformed(QtGui.QTransform().rotate(15))
        painter.drawPixmap(topX - 2, topY + 100, pixmap4)
        pixmap5 = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(RESPATH, "info.png"))
        painter.drawPixmap(topX + 20, topY + 125, pixmap5)
        pixmap6 = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(RESPATH, "run.png"))
        painter.drawPixmap(topX + 113, topY + 125, pixmap6)
        pixmap6 = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(RESPATH, "scripts.png"))
        painter.drawPixmap(topX + 137, topY + 85, pixmap6)

class RadialTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.scene=QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        buttonItem = RadialMenu()
        self.scene.addItem(buttonItem)
        buttonItem.setPos(100,100)
        buttonItem.setZValue(1000)
        self.scene.update()
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 305, 305)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    firstScene = RadialTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code will give this result

[image]

Comment: could you share the .png

Comment: @eyllanesc added images link too

Comment: @eyllanesc I just added a full working code .. but without any actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of objects, keeping a hierarchical object structure is always suggested. Also, when dealing with object that possibly have "fixed" sizes (like images, but not only), fixed positioning can be tricky expecially with newer system that support different DPI screen values.

With this approach I'm not using mapped images at all (but button icons can be still set), instead I chose to use a purely geometrical concept, using pixel "radius" values and angles for each button.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from math import sqrt

class RadialMenu(QtWidgets.QGraphicsObject):
    buttonClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.buttons = {}

    def addButton(self, id, innerRadius, size, startAngle, angleSize, pen=None, 
                  brush=None, icon=None):
        # if a button already exists with the same id, remove it
        if id in self.buttons:
            oldItem = self.buttons.pop(id)
            if self.scene():
                self.scene().removeItem(oldItem)
            oldItem.setParent(None)

        # compute the extents of the inner and outer "circles"
        startRect = QtCore.QRectF(
            -innerRadius, -innerRadius, innerRadius * 2, innerRadius * 2)
        outerRadius = innerRadius + size
        endRect = QtCore.QRectF(
            -outerRadius, -outerRadius, outerRadius * 2, outerRadius * 2)

        # create the circle section path
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        # move to the start angle, using the outer circle
        path.moveTo(QtCore.QLineF.fromPolar(outerRadius, startAngle).p2())
        # draw the arc to the end of the angle size
        path.arcTo(endRect, startAngle, angleSize)
        # draw a line that connects to the inner circle
        path.lineTo(QtCore.QLineF.fromPolar(innerRadius, startAngle + angleSize).p2())
        # draw the inner circle arc back to the start angle
        path.arcTo(startRect, startAngle + angleSize, -angleSize)
        # close the path back to the starting position; theoretically unnecessary,
        # but better safe than sorry
        path.closeSubpath()

        # create a child item for the "arc"
        item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem(path, self)
        item.setPen(pen if pen else (QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.transparent)))
        item.setBrush(brush if brush else QtGui.QColor(180, 140, 70))
        self.buttons[id] = item

        if icon is not None:
            # the maximum available size is at 45 degrees, use the Pythagorean
            # theorem to compute it and create a new pixmap based on the icon
            iconSize = int(sqrt(size ** 2 / 2))
            pixmap = icon.pixmap(iconSize)
            # create the child icon (pixmap) item
            iconItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap, self)
            # push it above the "arc" item
            iconItem.setZValue(item.zValue() + 1)
            # find the mid of the angle and put the icon there
            midAngle = startAngle + angleSize / 2
            iconPos = QtCore.QLineF.fromPolar(innerRadius + size * .5, midAngle).p2()
            iconItem.setPos(iconPos)
            # use the center of the pixmap as the offset for centering
            iconItem.setOffset(-pixmap.rect().center())

    def itemAtPos(self, pos):
        for button in self.buttons.values():
            if button.shape().contains(pos):
                return button

    def checkHover(self, pos):
        hoverButton = self.itemAtPos(pos)
        for button in self.buttons.values():
            # set a visible border only for the hovered item
            button.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red if button == hoverButton else QtCore.Qt.transparent)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.checkHover(event.pos())

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.checkHover(event.pos())

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        for button in self.buttons.values():
            button.setPen(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        clickButton = self.itemAtPos(event.pos())
        if clickButton:
            for id, btn in self.buttons.items():
                if btn == clickButton:
                    self.buttonClicked.emit(id)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.childrenBoundingRect()

    def paint(self, qp, option, widget):
        # required for QGraphicsObject subclasses
        pass

ButtonData = [
    (50, 40, QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxInformation), 
    (90, 40, QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxQuestion), 
    (180, 20, QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_FileDialogBack), 
    (200, 20, QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_DialogOkButton), 
    (220, 20, QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_DialogOpenButton), 
    (290, 30, QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowDown), 
    (320, 30, QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowUp), 
]

class RadialTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)

        buttonItem = RadialMenu()
        self.scene.addItem(buttonItem)
        buttonItem.buttonClicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        for index, (startAngle, extent, icon) in enumerate(ButtonData):
            icon = self.style().standardIcon(icon, None, self)
            buttonItem.addButton(index, 64, 20, startAngle, extent, icon=icon)

        buttonItem.setPos(150, 150)
        buttonItem.setZValue(1000)

        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.view.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 305, 305)
        self.show()

    def buttonClicked(self, id):
        print('Button id {} has been clicked'.format(id))
```

And this is the result:

[image: that's a cool radial menu!]

Comment: Perfect .. thank you so much and this what exactly I was looking for.